# How to re-order Views bulk operations for the user?

Tags: views, 8

How can I re-order the actions selected here? I don't want "Delete content" being the first item in the list on the actions select box for the end user.

[image]

Comment: [By default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIb9R.jpg), delete should be last. So the fact that yours is listed as first makes me believe that a custom or contrib module is already changing it's order. If you can figure out which one, look at how they did it there. Notice how vanilla VBO does not have "Available Actions" options there. So perhaps that module is altering the order.